# replace all line breaks not precede by a period with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

Is is possible to select only line breaks that are not preceded by a period using regular expressions ?
I am editing subtitles files for students. To make the printed version dead tree friendly I am trying to replace all the line breaks not preceded by a period or question mark with a space.

**option 1**
select all the line breaks not preceded by a period or question mark regex `[a-z]\n` works for that but then it of course selects the last letter of the word before the line break.
-> Is it possible to somehow save and insert the last letter of the word before the line break and insert that together with a space using regular expressions or do I have to write a script for that (say php)

**option 2**
Select only line breaks that are preceded by a character. I tried looking into lookbehind.

While writing this question the solution hit me.
To select a line break precede by a character do `(?<=[a-z])\n` and then replace with a space.

I searched stack overflow and could not really find what I was looking for. I hope I will not offend anybody by posting the question and solution at the same time. It might help someone else in the future.

Comment: You can answer your own question

Comment: If you have the answer to your own question, post and accept it. This is a standard thing you're expected to do on SO.

Comment: I agree with @Blender. You've got the right pieces. Just remember that ``.`` means "any character", whereas ``\.`` means "period" and ``\R`` is somewhat safer than ``\n``.

Comment: @mzedeler: I meant literally, OP can answer his question instead of editing the answer into the question body.

Comment: for any char not preceded by a dot, use  `[^.]` in your lookbehind

Comment: +1 for the nice gesture. You can click on the Answer Question button and answer your own question.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @wim See my updated answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem recently, I solved it like this:

search:

```
"(?<!\.|\?)(\r\n)+([^?\.]+)"
```

replace: (Be careful! There is a space!!)

```
" $2"


(?<!\.|\?) -> There can't be ./?
(\r\n)+ -> one or more newlines 
([^?\.]+) -> selects everything of the new line except ?/. 

" $2" -> second capture group with SPACE before.
```

I used Regex Buddy, if it doesn't work for you, I can try to convert it for you to another programming language using Regex Buddy.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax can vary depending on what you are using to replace the text (Java, Perl, PHP, sed, vi, etc.).

In Java you could try this :

```
str.replaceAll("([^\\.!?])\r?\n", "$1 ").replaceAll("  +", " ");
```

In perl :

```
perl -p -e 's/([^\.!?])\n/\1 /g; s/  +/ /g;' file.txt
```

You can also read this answer to a similar question :

[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

Comment: @wim hendrix This is option 1.
@Eric Citaire You don't need to escape a `.` inside a character class. Also, I believe the official recommendation in Perl is/was to use `$1` and not `\1` in the replacement string. There's an example at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters , but I haven't managed to find anything that says you shouldn't use `\1`. (In the regex itself, however, I'd still use `\1`.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's define a line break first. In some regex flavors, Java 8 / PHP (PCRE), Ruby (Onigmo), you may use a `\R` shorthand character class that matches any line break style. In [Java 8 regex reference, `\R` is defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as:

```
\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]
```

Now, you want to find this pattern if it is not preceded with `.` char. You need to use a *negative lookbehind*, `(?<!\.)`. It fails the match once it finds a `.` immediately to the left of the current location. So, here are some examples of how to remove the line break not preceded with a dot in some languages:

- PHP ([demo](https://ideone.com/e7Ms5x)): `preg_replace('~(\.\R+)|\R+~', '$1', $s)`
- Java 7 ([demo](https://ideone.com/FztaBo)): `String rx_R = "(?:\\u000D\\u000A|[\\u000A\\u000B\\u000C\\u000D\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029])"; String res = s.replaceAll("(\\." + rx_R + ")|" + rx_R, "$1");`
- Ruby ([demo](https://ideone.com/K5I7Gd)): `s.gsub(/(\.\R+)|\R+/, '\1')`
- C# (see [demo](https://ideone.com/aH422Y)): `var rx_R = @"(?:\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])"; var res = Regex.Replace(txt, $@"(\.{rx_R})|{rx_R}", "$1");`
- Python (both 2.x and 3.x) ([demo](https://ideone.com/lyLuun)): `rx_R = r'(?:\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])'` and then `re.sub(r'(\.{0})|{0}'.format(rx_R), lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else '', s)`
- JavaScript: it has no support for a lookbehind, thus, use a `([^.]|^)` capturing group and a backreference (`$1` to reference it from the replacement string) to keep the char other than `.` before a line break:

```js
var s = "Line1\u000D\u000A Line2\u000B Line3\u000C Line4\u0085 Line5\u2028 Line6\u2029 Line7";
var rx = /([^.]|^)(?:\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])/g;
console.log(s.replace(rx, '$1'));
```

Comment: Say I test a text whose EOL is \r\n. In PHP, I use `preg_replace('~(?<!\.)\R~', ' ', $s)` (replace **.EOL** with blank). \R will leave a blank after **.EOL**. But if I change _\R_ to _\r\n_ in regexp string, the blank is gone ok. Why?

Comment: @ScottChu It is due to the backtracking and the fact that `\R` is not a fixed-width pattern (you can see it by looking at the "unrolled" `\R` character class pattern, it may match 1 or 2 chars). Once the `\r` is found, a `.` is searched for immediately to the left of it. Since there is a `.`, `\r` is failed and the engine goes on to test the `\n` - and since it is preceded with `\r` (not a `.`), this `\n` is matched and replaced with a space. You must use `preg_replace('~(\.\R+)|\R+~', '$1', $s)` in PHP, see [**this demo**](https://ideone.com/e7Ms5x).

Comment: @ScottChu Thank you for letting know, I could improve the answer.